# Google TV + Mail(Gmail)

Tags: google-tv

I´m porting one app from HoneyComb to GTV.

One option of my app is send by mail some data, but I don´t see any apps related with mail functions.. 
It´s possible communicate via Intents with mail app´s on GTV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - simply because there is no mail app that comes pre-installed on Google TV. So you'd either need to setup your own email gateway server-side or require the user to download a mail application from Google Play. That said, I'm not aware of any compatible mail applications in Play for Google TV.